# hokuyo (URG-04LX) + imu (3DM-GX3-25) +hector mappping

Tags: imu, navigation, mapping, hokuyo, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using hokuyo (URG-04LX) + imu (3DM-GX3-25) and a mirror for height estimation to do 2D hector mappping and octomap to perform 3D mapping.all the frames transform are ok now . i know my hokuyo scan rate is not high enough,but this is the only laser scan i have. when i tested it around my lab, after turning the second corner map is not 90 degrees and  become messy.i know that imu only provide pitch and roll data to hector mapping,now i am trying use imu data for yaw angle to help the hokuyo and hector map perform better,but do not know how.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59965/hokuyo-(urg-04lx)-+-imu-(3dm-gx3-25)-+hector-mappping/) by [elva](https://answers.ros.org/users/4431/elva/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You shouldn't need to do anything. Just publish everything and it should use it if possible. One thing with the mirror: You'll need to filter that part out before passing it into any 2D SLAM algorithm. If you want some help about the algorithm performance, you'll need to provide some concrete data.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0